# Django plotly dash-application returning completely blank page when using django bootstrap components

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4, plotly-dash

I'm building a web application with Django and Dash and the excellent django_plotly_dash package. Everything is running smoothly, except for when I attempt to include Django bootstrap components. Adding even a single Django bootstrap component results in a totally blank page - even the html-divs from django_plotly_dash dissappear. Also, the `external_stylesheets` option seems to be totally ignored, even when `add_bootstrap_links=True`.

This produces the expected output:

```
import dash_html_components as html
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

dis = DjangoDash("test_app_dash",
                 add_bootstrap_links=True)

dis.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("THIS WORKS FINE"),        
    ]
)
```

While this produces a totally blank page (without raising any exceptions):

```
import dash_html_components as html
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

dis = DjangoDash("test_app_dash",
                 add_bootstrap_links=True)

dis.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("THIS WORKS FINE"),
        dbc.Alert("THIS DOES NOT WORK", id="base-alert", color="primary"),    
    ]
)
```

Here are some of the key files for a minimal working example (see [screenshot of full project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RP58.png)):

test_app views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from . import test_app_dash

def test(request):
    return render(request, "test_app/test.html")
```

main urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("test_app.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('django_plotly_dash/', include('django_plotly_dash.urls'))
]
```

test_app urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views as test_views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", test_views.test, name = "test")
]
```

snippet from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'channels',
...]

...
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379),],
        },
    },
}

X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

ASGI_APPLICATION = "test_app.routing.application"
```

test.html:

```
{% load plotly_dash %}

{% plotly_app name="test_app_dash" %}
```

It would be great if somebody could shed some light on this! I'm stumped. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

In test.html change `plotly_app` to `plotly_app_bootstrap`.